# Reactjs: Antd Table onRowClick trigger all event

Tags: reactjs, antd

So i'm new to reactjs, im doing a table that when you click on 1 row it will render a detail description  for that row. I have some button to trigger some event on that description table. But when i'm click the row on the table the description still render but the problem is, all the event in the descroption is trigger when i click on the row table not the button. Help pls
Here is my code:

```
const [displayCoursesDescription, setDisplayCoursesDescription] = useState({ coursesDescription: [] });
const handleCloseCoursesDescription = () => setDisplayCoursesDescription({ coursesDescription: [] });
const handleReloadCourse = () => {
      setDisplayCoursesDescription({ coursesDescription: [] });
      dispatchStudentCourses();
};

<div className="studentDashboardContent">
    <div className="TableHeader">
      <img className="courseIcon" src={courseActive} alt="courseActive" role="presentation" />
      <p className="courseText">Courses</p>
      <div className="ToolBar">
        <OutlinedButton
          icon={<ReloadOutlined style={{ width: '32px' }} />}
          color={COLOR}
          backgroundColor={BACKGROUND_COLOR}
          display="inline"
          onClick={handleReloadCourse}
        />
        <SearchBox
          placeholder="Search for courses"
          color={COLOR}
          backgroundColor={BACKGROUND_COLOR}
          display="inline" // inline || none
        />
      </div>
    </div>
    {courses && courses.status === API_STATUS.LOADING ? (
      <LoadingIndicator />
    ) : (
      <Table
        className="studentTable"
        columns={columns}
        dataSource={coursesSource}
        pagination={{ hideOnSinglePage: true }}
        onRow={(record) => ({
          onClick: (event) => {
            setDisplayCoursesDescription({ coursesDescription: record });
            getDepartmentById(record.department);
          },
        })}
      />
    )}
  </div>
  {displayCoursesDescription.coursesDescription.key ? (
    <div className="CourseDescription">
      <div className="HeaderButton">
        <a
          href={displayCoursesDescription.coursesDescription.hostname}
          className="courseUrl"
          rel="noreferrer"
          target="_blank"
        >
          <div className="forwardBtn" role="presentation">
            <p className="forwardText">Go to course</p>
            <img className="forwardImg" src={forward} alt="forward" />
          </div>
        </a>
        <Button className="closeBtn" type="primary" icon={<CloseOutlined />} onClick={console.log('click1')} />
      </div>
      <div className="courseCodeName">
        <p className="courseCode">{displayCoursesDescription.coursesDescription.code}</p>
        <p className="courseName">{displayCoursesDescription.coursesDescription.name}</p>
      </div>
      <p className="departmentTitle">DEPARTMENT</p>
      <div className="courseDepartment">
        <img className="departmentImg" src={departmentIcon} alt="department" />
        <p className="departmentName">{departments.name}</p>
      </div>
      <div className="courseDescription">
        <p className="descriptionTitle">COURSE DESCRIPTION</p>
        <p className="description">{displayCoursesDescription.coursesDescription.description}</p>
      </div>
      <Button className="unassignCourse" type="primary" danger onClick={console.log('click2')}>
        Exit course <LoginOutlined />
      </Button>
    </div>
  ) : (
    <div className="studentBackground">
      <div className="dashboardContainer">
        <p className="hiText">Hi {user.name}. How are you today?</p>
        <img className="dashboardIMG" src={dashboardIMG} alt="dashboardimg" />
      </div>
    </div>
  )}
```

Here is the console log that 2 onClick event were trigger when i click on the table Row
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yd1s2.png)

Comment: You are running your click handlers when the component renders.  Change your handlers so that they are wrapped in anonymous functions: `onClick={() => console.log('click1')}`.  When you have parenthesis after a function it means "run this when you encounter it".

Comment: omg, its work, thanks you so much jme11